# How do I use images in tables in read the docs CSV tables?

Tags: python, csv, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have a csv-table element, how do I put images in a cell? I'm using sphinx and building with Read The Docs. I've tried doing

```
(table.csv)

...

..image:: [image path]

...
```

but this only shows up as text.

Comment: You cannot do that with [csv tables](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#csv-table), because the values between commas are not interpreted by Sphinx.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this if it can help

[insert images and data from csv file to xlsx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019176/insert-images-and-data-from-csv-file-to-xlsx-file)